# Still getting facebook user id after logout on LARAVEL

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, laravel

I've been experiencing some problems with the facebook SDK on Laravel.

This is my code:

```
public function get_index() {
    $facebook = IoC::resolve('facebook-sdk');

    try {
        $fb_id = $facebook->getUser();
        if ($fb_id) {
            $token = array(
                'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
            );
            $fb_data = $facebook->api('/'.$fb_id.'?', $token);
            print_r($fb_data);
        } else {
            $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                    'scope' => Config::get('facebook.scope'),
                    'redirect_uri' => Config::get('facebook.landing_page')
                        ));
            echo "<script> top.location.href='".$url."'</script>";
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $exc) {
            $fb_id = NULL;
            echo $exc;
    }
}
```

If I logout from Facebook, it still gives me the fb_uid. A weird thing that happens is that if I login with other account, it doesn't print the current logged in account, but the last one. The only way to "destroy" the user is by deleting the cookies.

I've been working on CodeIgniter and the code works just perfect. Now I'm learning Laravel and trying to test my codes on it but can't go on if this doesn't work.

Any clues of whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the user needs to logout of the application itself in order for the User ID to be reset. You can logout URL for the user by calling `$facebook->getLogoutUrl();`

Comment: It still prints the user data, any clues?

Comment: It prints the user data because of the `print_r($fb_data);` line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to log out the currently logged in user from your application as well. So everytime a user logs out from your application, you should also destroy the users' facebook session.

Try this to destroy the user's facebook session on log out:

```
$facebook = IoC::resolve('facebook-sdk');
$facebook->destroySession();
```